# Configuring SharePoint intranet URLs

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, iis, dns

I need to configure the SharePoint intranet URL to show ‘Domain’.  Currently when I type that into my browser, it brings up the site, but switches to show ‘snb-sharepoint’.  It will also show up as ‘Domaintwo’.
Alternative access mappings are (everything is in http://):

-snb-sharepoint (default zone), public URL for zone is snb-sharepoint

-Domain (default zone), public URL for zone is snb-sharepoint

-Domaintwo (intranet zone), public URL for zone is Domaintwo

In IIS, I have one binding on port 80 with no host header ( * ) that will be a catch all site for that port.

On the DNS manager I have CNAMES for the URLs above:

1. CNAME = Domain
   FQDN = Domain.snb.companynb.com
   FQDN for target host = snb-sharepoint.snb.companynb.com
2. CNAME = Domaintwo
   FQDN = Domaintwo.snb.companynb.com
   FQDN for target host = snb-sharepoint.snb.companynb.com

I also have some networks drives that are mapped to SharePoint libraries.  Alternative access mappings changes made these network drives inaccessible 
Ex:
\Domain\docs1\
\Domain\docs2\

What do I need to configure in order for my SharePoint intranet URL to show ‘Domain’ and not take down my network drives that are mapped to SharePoint?

Comment: you want to browse the site using http://domain url not http://snb-sharepoint?

Comment: 'domain' is just an example of an intranet URL.  I didn;t want to give out my actual domain.  It could be  anything.  Ex. snb.intranet

Comment: Edit the public URL on the AAM page and enter the http://domains there.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue resolved by configuring "Domain" to a public URL instead of an internal URL.

Afterwards, when I type it in my browser it sticks rather than changing to snb-sharepoint.  Hope this helps others.